# Async nature of AngularJS with digest/apply

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, asynchronous

I've often had a problem where I had a scope variable set up in a parent controller, and the child controller calls this scope variable. However, it calls it before the function has been able to set the scope element, causing it to return undefined. Example:

Parent Controller:

```
module.controller('parent', '$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
$scope.init = function(profileID, profileViewStatus) {
    //Initiiaze user properities
    $http.get(requestUserInformationGetURL + profileID)
        .success(function(profile) {
            $scope.profile = profile;
            $scope.userID = profile.user_id;
            $scope.username = profile.username; 
            console.log($scope.userID);
        })
        .error(function() {
            exit();
        });
}
```

Child Controller:

```
module.controller('child', function($scope, $http, fetchInfo) {

console.log($scope.userID);

//Fetch the HTTP POST data for the user profile
var promise = $http({
    method: "post",
    url: fetchInfo,
    data: {
        user_id: $scope.userID //From the parent controller
    },
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
});
promise.then(function(successResponse) {
    //Populate the scope, log the data
    console.log(successResponse);
    $scope.data = successResponse.data;
}, function(error) {
    alert(error);
});
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="parent" init="init('<?php $user_id;?>')">
     <div ng-controller="child">
     </div>
 </div>
```

What often happens is that the userID will be reported back as undefined in the child controller, but then right after, it will be reported back as defined in the parent controller. Obviously, the child controller using the $scope.userID is being called before the init function in the parent controller is complete. How do I force AngularJS to wait in the child controller until the init function is complete? I've tried something like:

```
if (!$scope.userID) {
   $scope.$digest();
}
```

But it didn't work and I don't think it's the correct syntax. I guess, I don't fully understand the Asycn nature of AngularJS and this occurs multiple times. How do you control the DOM loading elements to solve something like this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proper way in this case would be to use dedicated service to handle async operations, requests, data caching, etc. But since you don't have service layer yet, I will propose simple Promise-based solution using controller scope promise object.

Check you modified code:

```
module.controller('parent', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.init = function (profileID, profileViewStatus) {
        $scope.profilePromise = $http.get(requestUserInformationGetURL + profileID).success(function (profile) {
            $scope.profile = profile;
            $scope.userID = profile.user_id;
            $scope.username = profile.username;
        })
        .error(exit);
    }
}]);

module.controller('child', function($scope, $http, fetchInfo) {

    // Fetch the HTTP POST data for the user profile
    $scope.profilePromise.then(function() {
        return $http({
            method: "post",
            url: fetchInfo,
            data: { user_id: $scope.userID },
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
        });
    })
    .then(function(successResponse) {
        console.log(successResponse);
        $scope.data = successResponse.data;
    }, function(error) {
        alert(error);
    });
});
```

As you can see, parent controller `init` method is still called, but now it immediately sets scope property `profilePromise`, which is accessible in child controller.

Child controller uses `then` method of the parent controller `profilePromise` object, which guaranties that `$http` request using `$scope.userID` will fire after profile is already available.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you would use a route resolve with the UI Router to ensure the work is done before either controller is constructed. Child states automatically have access to the resolves of their parent.

```
 //Router configuration
.state('app.inspections.list', {
    url: '',
    templateUrl: 'Template/parent',
    controller: "Parent as vm",
    resolve: {
        profile: ['$http', function ($http) {
            return $http.get(requestUserInformationGetURL + profileID)
                .success(function(profile) {                    
                    console.log(profile.userID);
                    return profile;
                })
                .error(function() {
                    exit();
                });
        }]
    }
}).state('parent.child', {
    url: 'child',
    templateUrl: 'Template/child',
    controller: "Child as vm"
})

   //parent controller
    module.controller('parent', '$scope', 'profile', function ($scope, profile){
        $scope.profile = profile;
        $scope.userID = profile.user_id;
        $scope.username = profile.username; 
    }

//child controller
module.controller('child', 'profile', function($scope, $http, fetchInfo, profile){

console.log(profile.userID);

//Fetch the HTTP POST data for the user profile
var promise = $http({
    method: "post",
    url: fetchInfo,
    data: {
        user_id: profile.userID //From the parent controller
    },
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
});
promise.then(function(successResponse) {
    //Populate the scope, log the data
    console.log(successResponse);
    $scope.data = successResponse.data;
}, function(error) {
    alert(error);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use promise ($q service) :try using this code:

parent controller :

```
$scope.init = function(profileID, profileViewStatus) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.get(requestUserInformationGetURL + profileID)
        .success(function(profile) {
            $scope.profile = profile;
            $scope.userID = profile.user_id;
            $scope.username = profile.username; 
            deferred.resolve($scope.userID);
            console.log($scope.userID);
        })
        .error(function() {
            deferred.reject('error');
            exit();
        });
       return deferred.promise;
}
```

Don't call init method in parent contrller.

in child controller:

```
$scope.init().then(function(userID){
    var promise = $http({
    method: "post",
    url: fetchInfo,
    data: {
        user_id: userID //From the parent controller
    },
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
   });
   promise.then(function(successResponse) {
    //Populate the scope, log the data
    console.log(successResponse);
    $scope.data = successResponse.data;
   }, function(error) {
    alert(error);
  });
})
.catch(function(error){
 console.log('error');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be that `$.get` is being called asynchronously, which is the default behavior. Your `init` method might actually be called in the order you're expecting but what's happening is:

- Parent `init` is called
- `$.get` is called, but the server's response is non-instantaneous
- Child `init` is called
- GET data bounces back from the server
- `$.get(..).success(function(data){...});` is called to deal with the data

I'd suggest what other people are, using promises to defer execution.